# PHP PCRE - match "nothing"

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to match my application uri to a set of routes, and for the default route I thought about allowing `bb.com/home` or `bb.com/` (empty) to be the allowed options on the first uri segment, and the same for the second. I'm not sure the way I am checking for empty values is the best :

```
#^/?(?P<controller>([.*]{0}|home))(?:/(?P<action>([.*]{0}|test)))?/?$#uD
```

*Notice the* `[.*]{0}`

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You could make it lazy: `.*?`, that should match nothing every time.

Comment: It worked, and is shorter than my approach.

Comment: Also, you don't have to have so many capture groups. You even have a numbered capture group within a named capture group. This is how I would write the expressions: `^/?(?P<controller>.*?|home)/(?P<action>.*?)/?$`

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis the second segment is set to optional.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Another simpler way of saying _"home or nothing"_  is to use an empty last alternative like so: `(?:home|)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it lazy: `.*?`, that should match nothing every time.

---

Also, you don't have to have so many capture groups. You even have a numbered capture group within a named capture group. This is how I would write the expression:

`^/?(?P<controller>.*?|home)/(?P<action>.*?|test)/?$`

This retains the two named capture groups, but gets rid of the nested numbered capture group and also the non-capturing group which was not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

By placing `.*` inside a character class `[]` you're asking to match a literal dot `.` and literal `*` instead of the dot being able to match any character (except newline) and `*` being able to act as a quantifier.

By using the `{0}` range quantifier, this matches exactly `0` times (`token is being ignored`). You're not going to get the results you expect and their is no need to do this either.

You could simply add the `?` for a non-greedy match and remove the excess capturing groups here.

```
~^/?(?P<controller>.*?|home)/(?P<action>.*?|test)/?$~i
```

However think about how this may work, you said you wanted to allow `bb.com/home`, well this will also match patterns that you possibly do not want.